# What is the purpose of `std::tuple_size<std::array>`

Tags: c++, stdarray

I have two questions concerning the helper class `std::tuple_size<std::array>` of `std::array`.

First, there is a constexpr `size()` member function in class `std::array`, why does one need `std::tuple_size<std::array>`?

Second, is the name `tuple_size` misleading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The design goal of `std::tuple_size` (and its friends `std::tuple_element` and `std::get`) is to work not only on literal `std::tuple`s, but on anything tuple-like. Something being tuple-like generally just means that it is a compound type containing a fixed number of ordered elements.

You can clearly see this abstraction in use by looking, for example, at how [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) are defined : they allow decomposing anything that has sensible implementations of `std::tuple_size`, `std::tuple_element` and `get<I>`.

Under this broadened notion of "tuple-like", it only makes sense that `std::array` (and `std::pair`) would specialize these traits to be handled as a tuple of N identical types (resp. a tuple of size 2).

Comment: In other words, "why not" :D

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the tuple interface, which `std::array` supports. The other parts are [`std::tuple_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_element) and [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get).

And `std::array::size` is also redundant, the size is specified as part of the type. That exists as part of the sequence container interface.

Comment: Not very redundant for the exact same reason,it is also not constexpr for no good reason at all..

Answer (score 1):

`std::tuple_size` and `std::tuple_element` and function templates called `get` provide a generic interface to "list of objects with constant count and types" which can be used in template programming without needing to specify types.

```
#include <utility>

template <class Tuple>
constexpr std::tuple_element_t<Tuple>& get_last(Tuple& t) {
    constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value;
    static_assert(size > 0);
    return get<size-1>(t);
}
```

This `get_last` function will work with `std::tuple`, `std::pair`, `std::array`, and any other user types that provide specializations for `std::tuple_size`, `std::tuple_element`, and a function template `get` in a namespace related to the type.

Also, the language itself looks for and uses `std::tuple_size`, `std::tuple_element`, and `get` when the structured binding syntax is used. Again this can be any of the same types, including a user-defined type that implements the interface.

```
using MyVec = std::array<double, 3>;
void f(const MyVec& v) {
    const auto& [x, y, z] = v;
    // ...
}
```